# Connect to UID based P2P IP Cam over web app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, p2p, ip-camera

I have an IP Cam with P2P connectivity based on Hi3518 chips. Currently I can connect it to internet and watch the stream using an Android app just by providing the UID on QR code and username and password present at the back panel of the camera.

Currently it is accessible via the android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=object.p2pwificam.client&hl=en

I am looking to develop a Node.js or a front end javascript based web app for the same purpose.